# SWI Prolog 5.8.3 - div is not a function?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

In my program I have a predicate `number_to_unique_bits_list`, that receives a number and a list of booleans, and returns a a boolean formula that satisfies when its value is the number.

```
number_to_unique_bits_list( 0, [], [] ).

number_to_unique_bits_list( IntegerNumber, [ Bit | RestBits ],[ ResultBit | RestResultBits ] ) :-
      ModRes is mod( IntegerNumber, 2 ),
      ModRes == 1,
      ResultBit = Bit,
      Divided is div( IntegerNumber, 2),
      number_to_unique_bits_list( Divided, RestBits, RestResultBits ).

number_to_unique_bits_list( IntegerNumber, [ Bit | RestBits ],[ ResultBit | RestResultBits ] ) :-
      ModRes is mod( IntegerNumber, 2 ),
      ModRes == 0,
      not_on_sat(Bit, ResultBit),
      Divided is div( IntegerNumber, 2),
      number_to_unique_bits_list( Divided, RestBits, RestResultBits ).
```

The problem occours when I get the following error:

> ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `div/2' is not a function

But checking in [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=div%2F2), I can see `div/2` is a function! I don't understand what's the problem?

Comment: Old versions of SWI did not have `(div)/2`.  For best results, get version 6.x.x.

Comment: @false That seems like an answer.

Comment: In systems supporting `(div)/2`, you can write `X is Integer div 2`